# InnerText doesn't update in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a game where on-click innerText of the object changes.
Below is the function from my JS file which is called on-click. In the console I can see the expected sign, but doesn't reflect on the page.

```
function printx(number){
    let isko = document.getElementById("r" + number);
    console.log(isko);
    if(isko.innerText==""){
        isko.innerText = sign;
        console.log(isko.innerText);
        checksign();
        disp.innerHTML= "<center>" + sign + " Turn " + "</center>" ;
        winner();
    }
}
```

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/c9ejhox4/

Comment: what is `disp`?

Comment: Please post some more code! A Fiddle would be great

Comment: can you share whole code ?

Comment: let disp = document.getElementById("player");
It is an object which is used in the header to change the heading.

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is discouraged. Plus, the [`<center>` tag is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: @RichaSharma please edit your question to include the full details. Is there really an element with the id "player"?

Comment: @NonameSL Added JS Fiddle. Yes there is an element with the id player. Thanks for the comments on center tag and innerHTML. Would change that.

Comment: Please edit your question with the full details. Your code is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the winner function loops through and resets innerHTML for every tile item for every turn. Make sure that loop is inside the if statement to check if someone actually won.

Answer (score 1):

for loop in winner() override text in td tag

Answer (score -1):

There are few errors that can be corrected.

1. Loop in winner() function must be inside the if condition.
2. innerText, innerHTML and some outdated attributes are used.
3. You must use jquery to avoid such lengthy code.

Update this code to jquery to see if the problem solve.